# How can I make it so I only score when character is actually jumping above block?

Tags: javascript, html

https://codepen.io/jeremymontes10/pen/YzaJeWP

This works to stop the game and say you lost...

```
  `if (blockLeft < 19 && blockLeft > 1 && characterTop >= 120) {
    block.style.animation = "none";
    alert("You got a score of " + (i-1) + "!");`
```

This changes the text every time you click the jump button but you could just keep pressing it and keep scoring.

```
`function text() {
    document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = i++;
}`
```

This is for the play again button to get the block moving again as well as set the score back to zero.

```
`function playAgain() {
  block.style.animation = "block 2s infinite";
  i = 0;
  document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = i++;
}`
```

Comment: The issue is that you increment the score every time the button is hit. So the easy solution is to not increment the score in the button, but instead link it to the object passing out of the screen, or to only increment the score if both the button is pushed and the object exits the screen.

Comment: Note also that Java is not the same thing as Javascript. I have edited your question to use the correct tag.